# AJAX calls from Apache-hosted file to Tomcat servlet on same server failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat

Why are my AJAX requests failing? I have a website

`www.foo.com`, and I'm running Tomcat on the same server, `www.foo.com:8080/services`. However, when a file on `foo.com` makes an ajax call as such:

```
$.get("http://foo.com:8080/services/action.do", null, myCallback );
```

I get an error response, rather than the xml document I get if I manually browser to the url given above. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Can you please post more details about the error response? Response status code? Error message? Anything in appserver logs?

Comment: Use fiddler or some other sniffer to see the difference in request and response when GETting directly from browser and GETting through XHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomcat is running on a differemt port (8080 as opposed to 80) it's regarded as a different origin, so you're running into [the same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript):

> Mozilla considers two pages to have the same origin if the protocol, **port (if one is specified)**, and host are the same for both pages.

(My emphasis).

Although this comes from the Mozilla docs, the policy is implemented the same way in all browsers - well, all browsers that are safe to use ;-)

Comment: Hard to say if this is really the cause as OP mentioned about an "error response" which is too ambiguous. It might have been a 405 method not allowed, or a 404 page not found, or 500 internal server error. Besides, the browser concern only applies on sharing the session/coookie information.

Comment: Nope, the same-origin policy applies to Ajax calls (more specifically, requests made using XMLHttpRequest). The jQuery `$.get()` method doesn't return any useful information beyond the word "error" IIRC, so that would be why there isn't any more information.

Comment: I'm getting HTTP 200 with an error. I guess I'll just have to serve my files off of tomcat as well, if I hope to make requests against Tomcat. I'll try it.

Comment: And that's not a mistake. I get HTTP 200 as a response, but my ajax call hits the error handler.

Comment: Yup. If I serve the files over Tomcat, it works. What a pain. I really think this is a poor behavior. I know I can trust my server, so why limit what ports I can connect on?